# QueryDocumentSnapshot seems to lack the methods of its parent class

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase to build a database application. I'm trying to get the firebase generated id of a particular document. The document is returned as a Promise, which returns a QuerySnapshot. A forEach loop pulls each QueryDocumentSnapshot out of the QuerySnapshot, so I'm working with the QueryDocumentSnapshot class. The documentation says that this class has the same API surface as the DocumentSnapshot class.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot

Since the DocumentSnapshot class has a getId() method, I thought I'd use that.

```
searchBooks(){

this.booksSearched = true;
this.bookService.getBookList(this.authorName).get().then(bookListSnapshot =>{
  this.bookList = [];
  bookListSnapshot.forEach( snap =>{
    this.bookList.push({
      authorLastName: snap.data().authorLastName,
      title: snap.data().title,
      edition: snap.data().edition,
      id: snap.getId() <-------ISSUE HERE----------- 
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

}

However, I get this error.

```
property 'getId' does not exist on type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'
```

Here is the code for the bookService

```
getBookList(authorLastName): firebase.firestore.Query{

  return this.bookListRef.where("authorLastName", "==", authorLastName);
}
```

What's even more wild is when I tried change my code around. Instead of pulling the QueryDocumentSnapshots out using the forEach loop, I thought I would take advantage of the fact that bookListSnapShot is a QuerySnapshot and call its getDocuments() method. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot

This would return a list of DocumentSnapshots, possibly meaning that whatever inheritance issue with the getId() method could be avoided. However, when I tried, I got this error:

```
var documents = bookListSnapshot.getDocuments();
Property 'getDocuments' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot'
```

To me, it seems like the documentation is being contradicted by the errors the editor is throwing. Does anyone know what's going on?

Thank you for reading,

-Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing code in JavaScript, but you're looking at API documentation for Android using Java.  Here are the JavaScript API docs for [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) and [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot).  DocumentSnapshot has a property called [id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#~id) that you're looking for.

Comment: Ohoho, embarassing. Thank you!